# Как задать ширину для кнопки

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Не получается почему-то установить фиксированную ширину для кнопки

```css
a.buttom1 {
 background-color: #9cbf3f;
 padding: 13px;
 border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 20px;
 width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="buttom1">Test</a>
```

Что я делаю нет так?

Answer (score 2):

добавьте ей

```
 display: block;
```

ссылке по другому ширину не зададите

Comment: тогда проблемка получается. мне нужно две кнопки такие на одной строке, а с display: block; этого не сделать

Comment: тогда `display: inline-block;`

Comment: тогда добавте еще float: left; и они станут в ряд, а под ними блок с clearfix( со стилем clear:both)

Comment: @stackanon точно. спасибо